# Howto run jupiter script as superuser in lubuntu-rc.xml?

Tags: lubuntu, sudo, openbox, jupiter

I'm trying to bind to my asus eee hotkeys couple of jupiter functions to work as on Windows. The problem is that I have to run those as superuser. Under terminal scripts are working fine so I put in my `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="XF86Launch6">
<action name="Execute">
<command>sudo /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/cpu-control</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

Aaaaaand... It partially works.

Some of files to change with this script was changed and other no. Some of the changed one are locked so sudo probably working. I have no idea how to debug this cause I don't know where to find log of this.

I'm lil' bit ashamed but I don't know how exactly sudo works.
I don't want to put my password every time to change cpu frequency or toggle touchpad so I don't want to use `gksu` or other sudo gui.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is ordering openbox to open a shell and run stuff. If you do a `ps ax | grep sudo` you will find a sudo instance hanging out waiting for your password. If you want to run a non-daemon command the best way is using the init-scrips:

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

And add your script at the start:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/cpu-control
exit 0
```

Or add an upstart script, if it's a daemon. Create the `/etc/init/jupiter.conf` script:

```
description "My jupiter script"

start on [2345]
stop on ![2345]

script
    exec /usr/lib/jupiter/script/cpu-control
end script
```

Comment: Its probably my bad language but You misunderstood me a little. As I read rc.local and /etc/init is kind of startup script and what I need is run script on demand to switch cpu frequency/wifi state. It's weird but ps aux shows nothing with sudo. So script is running correctly without password and then has no right to modify some of files. Example /usr/lib/jupiter/script/wifi has to check wifi state, switch it to opposite and write a new status to /var/jupiter/wifi_saved to send correct notification to daemon. But if I run it from shortcut key its only switch wifi state and left /var unchanged

Comment: @KamilKrzes they don't modify the files because they aren't run as root. `sudo` should be somewhere dangling after you "try" to run them waiting for you to input the password. You can modify the policykit rules to use `pkexec` and allow to be run without you inputting your password.